# Ajax adding and updating content on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Implementing Ajax requests in my rails 3 app has been one of the most frustrating things I've ever done. After days wasted trying to follow people's instructions online, the only thing that seems to work for me is ajax delete.

Users of my site have a profile page, which consists of some info at the top, then they have several different resumes, each of which is contained in a tab on the page. Within each resume are educations, which are what I'd like to be able to add and update dynamically. That is, User has_many resumes, and each resume has_many educations. I render each resume in a div with id equal to it's id. This is the div that I would like to have reload with ajax on form submission. Here's a little code.

user/show:

```
...
<%= render partial: 'shared/resume' %>
...
```

shared/resume:

```
<% if @resumes.any? %>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tabResumes">
     <%= render partial: 'shared/resume_item', collection: @resumes %>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate @resumes %>
<% end %>
```

shared/resume_item:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="<%= resume_item.id %>">
 ...
 # here I render a few different partials which display the different elements of the resume, such as educations. 
 # I'd like to reload this area on form submission.
 ...
</div>
```

educations_controller:

```
def create
@resume = Resume.find(params[:resume_id])
@education  = @resume.educations.build(params[:education])
respond_to do |format|
 if @education.save
  format.html  { redirect_to(@student, :notice => 'Education created.') }
  format.js
 else
  format.html {render :action => "new" }
  format.js
  end
 end
end
```

views/educations/create.js.erb

```
$('#<%=@resume.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript()%>"); //not sure what to call here, nothing I've tried has given me any success.
```

I'd also like to make updating refresh the same div, but I wanted to get create working first. Anybody have any advice for how to make this work? The ajax submit appears to be going through, as I am getting

```
Rendered educations/create.js.erb
Completed 200 OK in 52ms
```

in the console.

Comment: I do not understand. It seems you are trying to execute JS code on the template at server side, which is not possible. Where's is your client side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having your `create.js.erb` along the lines of:

```
$('#<%= @resume.id %>').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'shared/resume_item.html.erb') %>");
```

Alternatively you can also use the [jquery .appendTo method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), but, in this case I think `replaceWith` works better.

Comment: Okay so I just tried this.. no change on the page. I even tried it with a sample file with one line of text, but still nothing. I don't understand, it says it renders, but nothing happens to the page. Any idea why a page wouldn't respond to a request like this?

Comment: Do `resume_item` and other variables that are needed to render the partials still exist?  You can set a `debugger` and inspect the values to see if they exist.  Also, try looking the `Chrome Inspector Console` (or `Firebug`) to see if you're getting any `404` or similar errors.

Comment: In Firebug, under the post response it shows $('#7').replaceWith("<p>this is so annoying<\/p>\n"); where #7 is the id of the div I want, and that is the text of the one line file I made. It seems like its doing the right thing, just nothing happens

Comment: So after a little trouble shooting, it turns out that the code in my create.js.erb file is not executing. (if I copy the output and run it in the console, the correct result occurs). How can I change this?

Comment: @Dave Hmmm.. that's weird, given that, your console was outputting the following line `Rendered educations/create.js.erb`.  Anyhow, that would explain a lot.  In your form to create a new `education` - I hope you have `:remote => true` - that is what sends it as an `AJAX` request.